# What is the hidden message in this email?

Tags: word, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

**What is the hidden message in this email?**

> You recently purch*a*sed an item from C*h*icago *Z*ires:
>
> - Pr*o*duct Name: TI-06 The*r*mom*e*ter [*F*ANCY]
> - Product ID: 2016196120160206206240312172617201809010
> - Price: $122.61
> - Shippin*g*: FREE 32-day Shipping from *B*altimore
> - Method of Payme*n*t: Credit Card 1617-0707-1312-2116
>
> If *y*ou did not make this pur*c*hase, please click here to cancel.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>chchires*un*.*org*
> Order ID: 1461606166052501016081204130309616081902</sup>

**Hint 1:**

> First letters of each line are significant.

**Hint 2:**

> Erg... even I can solve it.

Comment: the stuff in italics is:  ahZoreFgBnycunorg

Comment: Does this need the [tag:steganography] tag?

Comment: If it doesn't, something's disastrously wrong.

Comment: (So I added it.)

Comment: I am being blunt now. If a cipher is involved(rot 13 can be excluded) you better tag it as such otherwise solvers will just get disgruntled.

Comment: @Sid I tagged it and added another hint.

Comment: I wonder why nobody has linked ["Code puzzles: What not to do?"](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do) yet, because this is a case in point. Only the hidden italics are "gettable"; the rest is just guesswork. There are too many numbers in the text. How are we supposed to know that we should look at the first letters of each line when they yield the nonsense word PPPSM? The "Even I" hint is probably meant to look at even digits or letters or whatnot. How can we get this from the puzzle _without the hint_? You can't fix a bad puzzle with hints.

Answer (score 2):

**PARTIAL ANSWER:**

So, the italics are: ahZoreFgBnycunorg

> Which rot 13s to *Numbers to Alphabets*)

Converting the Product ID and Order numbers to Alphabets(A=1.... Z=26), we get:

> Product ID- TPSFLAFBFTFXCLQZQTRIJ
>  Order number- NFPFPFEYAAFHLDMCIFPHSB

Random Thoughts:

> I think that the "F" is either E or space in the plaintext going by its sheer frequency.(I would say, to convert the numbers into letters on your own as I am liable to errors) This looks like some sort of letter substitution cipher and I am surprised the OP isn't tagged as such.

Comment: I had tried to turn the numbers to letters early on (on a whim; I didn't decode the hidden message), but I stopped when I hit the 60 in the Product ID, because I didn't like the idea that single-digit numbers somtimes have a leading zero and sometimes not. Does a leading zero have a meaning, is it, for example, a space? Or are the indices zero-based? That would mean that the Z is a BG. Anyway, this number-to-letters pattern isn't unique and your frequency analysis only as good as your assumtion whether 124 is ABD, AX or LD.

Comment: (But the digit pairs of the credit card are all valid letter indices. Converting them yields PQGGMLUP, which doesn't rot _x_ or atbash to anything useful as far as I can see.)

Comment: @MOehm while I agree that it doesn't currently convert to anything seeming useful, I think that the credit card might have something to do with it.

Comment: @MOehm I have added a hint.

Comment: @MOehm The [tag:cipher] tag has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Partial - >

As per the hint -

> First letter of each line is important. We get Y,P,P,P,S,M,I,C,O whose only meaningful anagrams are **COPY PIMPS** and **SPICY POP** which doesn't help ATM. If there is cipher involved, may be this forms a key. But not sure.

Comment: If we do Alphabets to Numbers, we get 25 16 16 16 19 13 9 3 15. Although it says Numbers to Alphabets, this might be a clue of some sort